# Custom TableViewCell not updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I want to set the checkmark in front of the cell. When I click on the checkmark icon the correct function is called and the datasource is changed.

[image: My Custom cell]

I call **[table reloadData]** and after that even **cellForRowAtIndexPath** is also called but it is always dequeing the old table cell and not reloading it with the new data source..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CheckboxCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath row: %d", indexPath.row);

// use CustomCell layout 
CheckboxCell *checkboxCell;

if(cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CheckboxCell" owner:self options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
            checkboxCell =  (CheckboxCell *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    checkboxCell =  (CheckboxCell *)cell; // return cell;
}

Observation *observation = [observations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd.MM.yyyy";
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSString *nowString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:observation.date];
[dateFormatter release];

NSString *amountString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", observation.amount];

checkboxCell.name.text = [observation.organism getNameDe];
checkboxCell.date.text = nowString;
checkboxCell.amount.text = amountString;
checkboxCell.latName.text = [observation.organism getLatName];

// Define the action on the button and the current row index as tag
[checkboxCell.checkbox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkboxEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[checkboxCell.checkbox setTag:observation.observationId];

// Define the action on the button and the current row index as tag
[checkboxCell.remove addTarget:self action:@selector(removeEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[checkboxCell.remove setTag:observation.observationId];

// Set checkbox icon
if(observation.submitToServer) {
    NSLog(@"CHECKED");
    checkboxCell.checkbox.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_icon.png"];
} else {
    NSLog(@"UNCHECKED");
    checkboxCell.checkbox.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.gif"];
}

[amountString release];
[observation release];

return checkboxCell;


// Set checkbox icon
if(observation.submitToServer) {
    NSLog(@"CHECKED");
    checkboxCell.checkbox.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_icon.png"];
} else {
    NSLog(@"UNCHECKED");
    checkboxCell.checkbox.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.gif"];
}

[amountString release];
[observation release];

return checkboxCell;
```

}

I think I'm doing something in the cellForRowAtIndexPath wrong.. Can anybody help me?

**Edit:**

The first problem could be fixed *(Thanks to Maggie)*. Now the checkmark is changing the first time correctly. But somehow if I change it on another cell its crashing on the following line:

```
- (void) checkboxEvent:(UIButton *)sender
{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:button.tag];

for(Observation *ob in observations) {

    if(ob.observationId == [number intValue]) { // <---- IT'S CRASHING HERE
        ob.submitToServer = !ob.submitToServer;

        NSLog(@"New value: %@", (ob.submitToServer) ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    }
}

[table reloadData];
}
```

But the observation object isn't nil. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
 else {
    return cell;
}
```

part with

```
 else {
    checkboxCell =  (CheckboxCell *)cell;
 }
```

and fill your checkboxCell with apropriate data.

Comment: Yeah I just found out that mistake by rereading my post. I changed it to your proposed line but than I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I trying to debug and locate it. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: After debugging:
The first time it is working. But when I try to set the checkmark on another cell it's directly crashing with a BAD_ACCESS and its not even going into the cellForRowIndexPath method. Not sure yet, why this is happening..

Comment: not sure what amountString is, but be sure it is not released too soon.

Comment: Yeah it's released at the end of the method. I've added above the whole code for the method. This is the log message: -[__NSCFDictionary observationId]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d5c820 I guess somewhere the observation object is nil..

Comment: of course. no need to release observation at the end of your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Yeah... Stupid mistake. It's working now! Thanks a lot for taking the time.